# Rails 7 Puma 6 & Mina setup : Mina fails to update server with new releases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, apache-mina

The setup (rails7 with puma 6 on debian 11 started with systemd - all in order) is pretty straightfoward but symlink is not updated :

ls -la on the current directory show the link remains hanged at the first release:

> current -> /home/deploy/production/app/releases/1

extracts from deploy.rb

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/version_managers/rbenv'

set :forward_agent, true
set :rbenv_use_path, '/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin/rbenv'

set :shared_dirs, fetch(:shared_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/assets')
set :shared_files, fetch(:shared_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 
                                                'config/master.key', 
                                                'config/credentials/production.key' )

task :remote_environment do
  invoke :'rbenv:load'
end

task :setup do
  
  in_path(fetch(:shared_path)) do
    command %[mkdir -p config]
    command %[touch "#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/database.yml"]
    command %[touch "#{fetch(:shared_path)}/config/puma.rb"]
    command %[chmod -R o-rwx config]
  end

end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy do
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    on :launch do
      in_path(fetch(:current_path)) do
        command %{mkdir -p tmp/}
        command %{touch tmp/restart.txt}
        command %{sudo service puma restart}
        command %{sudo service sidekiq restart}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

mina deploy verbose :

```
-----> Deploy finished
-----> Building
-----> Moving build to /home/deploy/production/app/releases/3
       $ mv "$build_path" "$release_path"
       $ cd "$release_path"
-----> Build finished
-----> Launching
-----> Updating the /home/deploy/production/app/current symlink
       $ ln -nfs "$release_path" "/home/deploy/production/app/current"
       $ cd "/home/deploy/production/app/current"
       $ cd /home/deploy/production/app/current
       $ mkdir -p tmp/
       $ touch tmp/restart.txt
       $ sudo service puma restart
       $ sudo service sidekiq restart
       /homedeploy/production/app/current
-----> Done. Deployed version 3
```

I do not know how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

During the setup time, I had created a "current" folder to test prior to deploying with mina.  That caused the issue: "Current" in Mina ways is a symlink.  It should not exist prior to minia setup as Mina needs to setup in a clean destination environment.

https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/issues/79